# TableView navigation - All the lables, textfields and images in one single ViewController or separate ones?

Tags: xcode, view, navigation, tableview, label

I'm in the start phase of my first iPhone app. Its a tab based application where each of the tabs represent a TableView menu with x cells, leading to other menus. 
As I'm getting started, after watching several tutorials, reading lots of info from Apples database, here at sof etc, and I'm actually really confused as I'm getting along in x-Code.. Some basic things are slowly getting clearer, but.. There are so many options and so many ways to to things right and wrong, and I'm afraid of making big mistakes and screw it all up. But back to the point:

What this app is all about is red wine. Its a guide/register over red wines sold in Norway with bottle imgs, info about price, taste, etc. Now that the TableView main menu is slowly starting to take form, I'm starting to think about the wine register cells and how to delegate the info in the detail View(s).

Should I create only one DetailView for the WinelistMasterViewController, and add the info about the wines as lables/textfields/images onto the background image in the storyboard, coded to show according to which cell you press in the list?

With more than 100 wines this seems like a big mess with all those lables in one view, it seems more tidy to make 100 views and make the connections from the WinelistMasterViewController to each of the tableviews. Why shouldn't I do it this way? I hope some of you can give me some directions. This is how I'm building the storyboard:

TabBarController --> Navigation Controller for tabs. In this case: Tab 2: The Wines --> TableView with cells to choose if you want to show the wine table alfabetically, by popularity, price, etc --> TableView with the Wines in the chosen order (cells with text, bottle image and favourite star ---> full screen background img with all the info about the wine you chose, and you will also be able to swipe between the wines, add to favs etc..

I'm a beginner so I have one hell of a job in front of me figuring out how to code up all this in the delegate and xviewcontrollers. But I do it with patience, one thing at the time, trying and failing and learning and slowly things take form.. But this seems like kind of a major issue which, I guess, determines much about how complicated the coding have to be later on.

I also want to mention that later on I will add a search function to rule and sort the list by needs, so it all should be adapted for this as well.. On advance, thank you for all help with this project! References to tutorials, articles, websites and other that can help me on my way, is also very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a plist of dictionaries for the wines, and as they are all similar (name key, district key, country key, etc), I populated a prototype cell in a TableView and made a "prototype" detailview for displaying the details. So I ended up with only 2 view controllers: 1 TableViewController and 1 DetailViewContoller. Much easier than making one viewcontroller for each wine...